# How does the GRUB 2 UEFI loader know where to look for the configuration file (or where the 2nd stage's files are located)?

Tags: boot, uefi, grub, grub2, guid-partition-table

If I use GRUB 2 on a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)-enabled partition, how does the loader "know" where to find its configuration file and other second stage's files?

Note: I found some mentions about a configuration file which is located in the same folder as GRUB's EFI loader and contains a chained load of "primary" configuration file from the specified partition, but that definitely is not true; there is only one "something.efi" file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are actual several ways this can happen:

- Load an embedded configuration file.
- Load a configuration file in the same directory as the GRUB binary.
- Load a configuration file from a path decided at `grub-mkimage` (called by `grub-install`) execution time.

The latter is probably the functionality you are really asking for, and it's a combination of the default configuration file name (`grub.cfg`), the *prefix* (default `/boot/grub`, but it can be explicitly specified to `grub-mkimage`) and the GRUB partition name for the partition where the prefix is located.

If I run `strings /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi | tail -1` on my current workstation, it prints out the stored value: `(,gpt2)/boot/grub`, telling `grubx64.efi` to look for its configuration file in /boot/grub on GPT partition 2. The bit before the comma (the GRUB disk device name) gets filled in at runtime based on which disk the `grubx64.efi` image itself was loaded from.

Dynamically loaded modules will also be searched for under this location, but in an architecture/platform-specific directory - in this case `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi`.

Comment: So they make (patch) a now unique loader executable for every installation. But how can they sign it for secure boot in this case?

Comment: And they also can only use GPT partition indexes, not UIDs. But the indexes aren't constant for GPT. GPT has partition UIDs for such purposes.

Comment: All Linux distros that support UEFI Secure Boot ship with a utility called "shim", which is itself signed with a key held by UEFI, and in turn manages a local keystore.

https://github.com/mjg59/shim

No comment on the GPT index really, other than I guess since the expected workflow is to re-run grub-install if you change your partitioning, that would still get resolved. It works the same regardless of partitioning scheme.

Comment: Secure Boot-signed UEFI GRUB binaries will usually have their prefixes set to just `/efi/<name of distribution>`, using the run-time default values for the disk and partition - and those default values are "whatever disk and partition the `grubx64.efi` was loaded from".

Answer (score 5):

For an EFI image, I found that `grub-install` or `grub-mkimage` will **always** embed an *early configuration* into the resulting EFI binary, regardless of whether or not you have specified the `--config FILE` option.

If you do not specify the `--config FILE` option, it will try to embed `/boot/grub/x86-64_efi/load.cfg`.

This early configuration file looks like this:

```
search.fs_uuid 8ef704aa-041d-443c-8ce6-71ac7e7f30da root hd0,gpt1
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg  # This line seems can be omitted, because
                             # it seems to be the default next action
```

- The `uuid` means the UUID of the file system, not of partition. You can use blkid to list it.
- The `hd0,gpt1` is just a hint.
- You can change the first line into `set root=hd0,gpt1`

This default behavior of auto embedding is different from BIOS mode. The latter by default only embeds a prefix string like `(,gpt3)/boot` without bothering with *search.uuid*.

I also found that the [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) EFI image embedded an early configuration like *[build-efi-images](https://source.puri.sm/pureos/core/grub2/blob/master/debian/build-efi-images#L64)*

```
if [ -z "\$prefix" -o ! -e "\$prefix" ]; then
    if ! search --file --set=root /.disk/info; then
        search --file --set=root /.disk/mini-info
    fi
    set prefix=(\$root)/boot/grub
fi
if [ -e \$prefix/$platform/grub.cfg ]; then
    source \$prefix/$platform/grub.cfg
elif [ -e \$prefix/grub.cfg ]; then
    source \$prefix/grub.cfg
else
    source \$cmdpath/grub.cfg
fi
```

The `cmdpath` is the directory of the EFI binary, so it will fall back to the *grub.cfg* file in the same directory of the EFI binary, as you found.

Comment: Where did you get this from? How can I check this early configuration file?